# Создание базы данных с начальными параметрами

Tags: golang, postgresql, sql

Я создаю базу данных используя postgres. Вопрос в том, как это делать правильно. Если я просто прописываю `CREATE TABLE ...`, то если база табличка пустая, postgres работает с ней очень странно: виснет на выборке, отбрасывает связанные объекты и т. д. Каким образом надо создавать базу/таблицы, чтобы подобных проблем не возникало?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, пример — что за таблицу Вы создаете и какой выполняете запрос, что Postgres виснет на выборке. Чем пример минималистичнее, тем лучше.

Answer (score -2):

Используйте pgadmin. Там вам просто нужно будет выбрать параметры и не нужно ни над заморачиваться

Answer (score -2):

Решилась проблема следующим образом. В запросе были непечатные символы. И когда такой символ встречался значением параметра в блоке Where, Postgres просто зависал. Возможно бага не в постгресе, а в самом драйвере. Для устранения вредных символов я использоввал кодировку Base64.